# Mueller matrix and Lorentz group

Tags: optics, visible-light, resource-recommendations, polarization

I have just learned about Stokes vectors and Mueller matrices for description of polarized light. In the text I studied there is clear restriction for the Stokes vector $\vec S$ that $S^2_0=S^2_1+S^2_2+S^2_3$ but not characterization of Mueller matrices is given, they just say it is matrix $4\times 4$.

Obvious restriction is that Mueller matrix has to transform a Stokes vector to a Stokes vector. From the condition on Stokes vector $S^2_0=S^2_1+S^2_2+S^2_3$ we can see that Mueller matrix has to be a multiple of an element of group $O(3,1)$.

Can you direct me to some text where the connection between Mueller matrices and Lorentz group is made? I did a quick google search and got many articles about this topic. So I'm looking for concise exposition to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PhD. Thesis:

[Hannah Dunstan Noble, "Mueller Matrix Roots"](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwj69v2fnOrNAhUEj5QKHcZfAcYQFgguMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Farizona.openrepository.com%2Farizona%2Fbitstream%2F10150%2F204893%2F1%2Fazu_etd_11728_sip1_m.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHttH8-Az4OPuh1v2KxcCAoRxZZzg&sig2=ln_Fo7JbRTX20lXbCOu06w)

gives a gentle introduction to the concepts and

[José J. Gil, "Characteristic Properties of Mueller Matrices", JOSA A, **17**, pp328-334](http://www.unizar.es/gom/Characteristic%20properties%20of%20Mueller%20matrices.pdf)

derives necessary and sufficient conditions for a matrix to be a physical Mueller matrix.

The situation is not quite as simple as you assume, although the group $\mathbb{R}\times SO(1,\,3)$ is an important special class of Mueller matrices. You seem to be forgetting partially depolarized light, which has $S_0^2 - S_1^2-S_2^2 - S_3^2>0$ as a strict inequality, and that, theoretically, some systems can decrease the degree of polarization. It's true that if an element leaves perfectly polarized light perfectly polarized, it must map the cone  $S_0^2 = S_1^2+S_2^2+S_3^2$ to itself, whence you can derive what you already know, that we're dealing with a member of $\mathbb{R}\times SO(1,\,3)$.